# voice calling using sinch

Tags: ios, swift, sinch

I am creating app with Sinch Voice calling from app to phone number first i am showing you my code then after i explain whats the exact issue

```
import UIKit
import Sinch

class ViewController: UIViewController,SINClientDelegate {
    func clientDidStart(_ client: SINClient!) {
        print(client)
    }

    func clientDidFail(_ client: SINClient!, error: Error!) {
         print(client)
    }


    var client: SINClient?
    var call: SINCall?

    @IBOutlet weak var txtCall: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnCall: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        initSinchClient()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    @IBAction func btnCall(_ sender: Any) {
        if call == nil {
            call = client?.call().callPhoneNumber(txtCall.text)
            btnCall.setTitle("Hangup", for: .normal)
        } else {
            call?.hangup()
            btnCall.setTitle("Call", for: .normal)
        }
    }
    func initSinchClient() {
        client = Sinch.client(withApplicationKey: "App Key", applicationSecret: "App Secret", environmentHost: "api.sinch.com", userId: "3")
        client?.delegate = self
        client?.setSupportCalling(true)
        client!.start()
    }

}
```

as you can able to see my code when i press call button then i can able to see logs here "https://portal.sinch.com/#/logs" but its giving me status Failed and failure  let me add screen shot of log so you can easily understood 
[image: Please Check i am geeting status like this]

so please help me which i have to do for get proper status

Comment: Do you have money in your account? What number are you trying to call? The test credit will only allow you to call your registered phone.

Comment: I am trying to call my own number and registered means where i have to register my phone number ?

Comment: @cjensen and if i want to call on all other number which is not registered then what i have to do?

Comment: i have another confusion is that call is properly sent but while calling its not ringing so whats solution for that please tell me

Answer (score 0):

In the Sinch Documentation there ist he following written:

> App-to-phone calls can be tested by calling the following test number:
>   +46000000000. When placing a call to this number, you will hear a voice prompt stating that the call has been connected, and shortly
>   after that the call will automatically be ended.

Have you tried this?
Best regards